# Show the UILabel's text with enough width

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following the *iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide*, I try to make a Quiz project using in objective-c.

The ViewController.m code here

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) int currentQuestionIndex;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *questions;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *answers;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    // Call the init method implemented by the superclass
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if (self) {
        // create two arrays filled with questions and answers
        // and make the pointers point to them

        self.questions = @[@"From what is cognac made?",
                          @"What is 7+7?",
                          @"What is the capital of Vermont?"];

        self.answers = @[@"Grapes",
                         @"14",
                         @"Montpelier"];
    }

    // Return the address of the new object
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender
{
    // Step to the next question
    self.currentQuestionIndex++;

    // Am I past the last question?
    if (self.currentQuestionIndex == [self.questions count]) {
        // Go back to the first question
        self.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    }

    // Get the string at that index in the questions array
    NSString *question = self.questions[self.currentQuestionIndex];

    // Display the string in the question label
    self.questionLabel.text = question;

    // Reset the answer label
    self.answerLabel.text = @"???";
}

- (IBAction)showAnswer:(id)sender
{
    // What is the answer to the current question?
    NSString *answer = self.answers[self.currentQuestionIndex];

    // Display it in the answer label
    self.answerLabel.text = answer;
}

@end
```

But running with non visual text When I tap the button, I have connected all the IBOutlets and actions. It seems like have compile error message report.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The UILabel with enough width.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing. I didn't understand. Sorry.

Comment: I'd suggest you retrieve a newer version of that guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works just fine, the only problem is that the arrays are not initialized. 
You can see it by yourself by putting a breakpoint at the end of `initWithNibName:bundle:` and one at the beginning of `showQuestion:`: the first breakpoint will never be called, and when you tap the "Show question" button you'll see that a `po self.questions` returns nil.

If you are using storyboards (which is the default case in all Xcode projects since quite a lot of versions) your view controller will never call `initWithNibName:bundle:` because this method is intended for initialization of xib-based view controllers.

You should put that code in the `viewDidLoad` method, so that the two arrays are correctly filled in.

Comment: how can I change my code to adjust for storyboard version?

Comment: just rename `- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` to `-(void)viewDidLoad`.

Comment: (and perhaps add a `[super viewDidLoad];` line at the beginning of that method, just to be fully compliant)